# nginx rails send_file - Duplicate headers received from server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, nginx, unicorn

I have set up our Rails app to serve files via `send_file` and since we dont want to keep our app busy serving the file we hand that off to Nginx with the `X-Accel-Redirect` header. For that i set `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'` in my `production.rb` file as well as setup my nginx.conf like this:

```
# In order to get the site running
# symlink this file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/production

upstream unicorn-production {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 3000;
  server_name production.localhost;
  root /home/deployer/apps/production/current/public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/production_access.log;
  rewrite_log on;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location ~ ^/downloads/(.*)$ {
    internal;
    alias /home/deployer/downloads/$1;
  }

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn-production;

    proxy_set_header  X-Sendfile-Type   X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_set_header  X-Accel-Mapping   /downloads/=/home/deployer/downloads/;

    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and in my controller action i do something like:
`send_file "/home/deployer/downloads/testfile.foo"`

.

This should all work in theory but when i visit `mysite.com/mycontroller/download` Chrome tells me `Duplicate headers received from server: Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION): Multiple Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.`

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can be fixed by wrapping the content disposition filename in quotes when using send_data:

From:

```
send_data data, :type => type,
          :disposition=>"attachment; filename=#{filename}"
```

To:

```
send_data data, :type => type,
          :disposition=>"attachment; filename='#{filename}'"
```

I assume the same applies when using the send_file method

See: https://github.com/prior/prawnto/pull/16

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( - the error goes away when I do: disposition: "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"" but then the downloaded filename is: "20150514_015108_to_015208.mp4-, attachment" - seems Chrome adds "-, attachment" for some unknown reason :/